# How to get a value from the context dictionary without looping through it

Tags: django, django-templates

I have to list the products belonging to a particular category and also above the products I want to display the name of the category (only once).
I can get the name of category when iterating over products but I want to display it only once on the top.

My models are follwing:

```
class category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    
class product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500,null=True, blank=True )
    category = models.ForeignKey(category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cost = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):  # new
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and the view is:

```
class ProductsListView(ListView):
model = product
template_name = 'products/productList.html'
context_object_name = 'products'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return (
            super()
            .get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
            .filter(category_id=self.kwargs['cat_id'])
        )
```

template code:

```
{% extends 'products/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}


<h1>Product PAGE!!</h1>

<!-- I want to display the category name here -->

{% for product in products %}

<img src="{{ product.image.url }}" alt="{{ product.name }}" width="10%">

<h2>{{product.name}} </h2>
<h2>{{product.cost}} </h2>
<h2>{{product.description}} </h2>


{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

I tried it using the key method "products[category] but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In template

```
Category : {{products.0.category.name}}
```

Above the for loop

Comment: Getting the error:
TemplateSyntaxError at /3
Could not parse the remainder: '[0].category.title' from 'products[0].category.title'

Comment: Thankyou, your solution works. So according to your solution instead of indexing the usual way products[0], we can index by using '.' am I right?

Comment: @MohamedElKalioby Another approach is by using `first`  and `with` like I have done in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [first](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#first) and [with](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#with) template tags like this:

```
{% with product=products|first %}
  {{product.category.name}}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Actually I don't want the name in every iteration that I am doing for products. Instead I want to show it only once, as a header.

Comment: @shubdb Sorry I had misread your question I have updated the answer with another approach.